# jquery attribute selector escape doublequote

Tags: jquery, attributes, selector

I want to select a html element (type text) by attribute selector. This works, but only if the attribute doesn't contain a double quote.

[image]

Is there a solution to avoid this problem with single/doublequotes?

Comment: Yes, there is: `$('input').filter(function() { return $(this).attr('attr_beforevalue') == Parameter; }).parent(...`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to select only `<input>`s with `attr_beforevalue` attribute value equaled to `Parameter` value:

```js
var Parameter = '"test"';
$('input').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('attr_beforevalue') == Parameter;
}).hide();
```

```html
<input attr_beforevalue='"test"' value='"test"' />
<input attr_beforevalue='test' value='test' />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it tomorrow, but it sounds great :)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all the `"` with a blank by doing the following

```
Parameter.replace(/\"/g, '')
```

so your code would look like

```
$('input[attr_beforevalue="'+Parameter.replace(/\"/g, '')+'"]').parent(...
```